# Restrict number to 0-5 round up or down if higher on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html

My scenario is I have 4 elements on my page that represent a rating these can all be different from each other.

The math isnt entirely accurate on the rounding of these so occasionaly I will get `5.5/5` or `.19.5/5` on my rating as well as `data-progress="110"` or `data-progress="-390"`

```
<div class="radial-progress blue-radial" data-progress="110">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="mask full">
      <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mask half">
      <div class="fill"></div>
      <div class="fill fix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inset">
    <div class="percentage">
      <div class="numbers">Product <span>5.5/5</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="radial-progress red-radial" data-progress="110">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="mask full">
      <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mask half">
      <div class="fill"></div>
      <div class="fill fix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inset">
    <div class="percentage">
      <div class="numbers">Seller <span>5.5/5</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="radial-progress yellow-radial" data-progress="-390">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="mask full">
      <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mask half">
      <div class="fill"></div>
      <div class="fill fix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inset">
    <div class="percentage">
      <div class="numbers">Shipping <span>-19.5/5</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My hacky non efficient way of fixing this problem has been targeting the number via `:contains`

```
if ($('.blue-radial span:contains("5.5")')) {
  $('.blue-radial span').html('5/5')
  $('.blue-radial').attr('data-progress', '100')
}

if ($('.blue-radial span:contains("5.5")')) {
  $('.blue-radial span').html('5/5')
  $('.blue-radial').attr('data-progress', '100')
}

// ETC...
```

I don't want to have to target for every possible variation is there a better way of going about this without having to do a bunch of `if` statements like a catch all to round down to either `100` `5/5` or `0`?

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$rates['desc']['score'] = 4.0;
$rates['service']['score'] = 4.0;
$rates['shipping']['score'] = 4.0;
$rates['desc']['score'] = floor((($rates['desc']['score'] - 3.9) * 5) * 2) / 2;
$rates['service']['score'] = floor((($rates['service']['score'] - 3.9) * 5) * 2) / 2;
$rates['shipping']['score'] = floor((($rates['shipping']['score'] - 3.9) * 5) * 2) / 2;
$average = floor((($rates['desc']['score'] * 0.5) + ($rates['service']['score'] * 0.2) + ($rates['shipping']['score'] * 0.3)) * 2) / 2;
?>
```

This is how I am getting the initial numbers

Comment: do you know what a mathematical equation is ?

Comment: Surprisingly I do I'm just wondering if there's a `foreach` type of way of doing this

Comment: Where's the "inaccurate" math done? Maybe it can be fixed from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.numbers').find('span').each(function(){
   var text = $(this).text().split('/')[0];
   if(parseFloat(text) > 5) {
     $(this).html('5/5')
  $(this).closest('.radial-progress').attr('data-progress', '100')
   }
   if(parseFloat(text) < 0) {
     $(this).html('0/5')
  $(this).closest('.radial-progress').attr('data-progress', '0')
   }
});
```

see demo:https://jsfiddle.net/bsbuy3p8/